# slicing pandas recommendations

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas, and I am having trouble getting to slice a panda object.

Let us say I have a panda data frame, then I slice the first row, and then I want to return the value of a given column:

```
>>> df['place_of_birth']
0    Italy
Name: place_of_birth, dtype: object
>>> type(df['place_of_birth'])
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

How can I get Italy as a string instead of the whole panda series object that I have now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't slice your dataframe, use this command:

```
df['place_of_birth'][0]
```

Comment: couldn't be more trivial, new to pandas, but i should have used intuition, thanks so much though!

Comment: This answer is misleading and not the correct way to go about it.  Please see docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html  This answer will fail when the index is an integer and 0 is not the first row